# Why this code works if is suppose that an Inteface it is fully abstract?

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors

Hello I'm new in java and I was testing the follow code in a java compiler but as my understanting an interface can´t have concrete methods but this one has concrete methods and works, can you explain me why ?? and output

> "Sprinting!"

```
interface Run {
    default void walk() {
        System.out.print("Walking and running!");
    }
}
interface Jog {
    default void walk() {
        System.out.print("Walking and jogging!");
    }
}
public class Sprint implements Run, Jog {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.print("Sprinting!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sprint().walk();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since [tag:java-8], interfaces have default methods.

Comment: Interfaces can have default methods since Java 8. [oracle docs - Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Comment: and those default methods can write inside them ??

Comment: Maybe just research what default methods are? Seems strange to try and explain it in the comments when there are thousands of pages of documentation to be looked at.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there are a few low quality Java Tutorial sites (not naming names) that say that Java interfaces are "fully abstract"; i.e. that you can't include method *code* in an interface.  And there are a lot of *old* articles and blogs that say the same thing.  (And *old* textbooks too.)

This used to be true.  Prior to 2014.  It is not true anymore ... for *any* version of Java that is not past end-of-life.

In Java 8, the language was extended to support `default` methods.  These are complete (i.e. not implicitly abstract) methods declared / defined in the interface itself.  These `default` methods are inherited by all classes that implement the declaring interface, and can be overridden ... like methods inherited from a class.

The thing that sets a `default` method apart from a method in (say) an `abstract` class is that a `default` method cannot directly refer to any instance fields.  The only way for a `default` methods to refer to the state of `this` is via other (non-default) method calls.

For more information about default methods, read the Oracle Java Tutorial:

- [The Java™ Tutorials: Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

There is a lot more (correct / up to date) information on how inheritance works in Java in the surrounding pages.

---

In your example, you have two interfaces (`Jog` and `Run`) that both declare a `default` method with signature `walk()`.  Your `Sprint` class implements both interfaces so both `walk()` methods are (notionally) inherited.  That would be ambiguous ... if it weren't for the fact that `Sprint` also overrides the inherited `walk()` with its own declaration.

So ... when you call `walk()` on a `Sprint` object you get the override.